# Error in run Android app on Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create Android app in Eclipse, connect to VM( adb connect 192.168.56.101 ). Then I try run app **Run As -> Android Application** and I have error

```
 [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] ------------------------------
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Android Launch!
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] adb is running normally.
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Automatic Target Mode: using device '192.168.56.101:5555'
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Uploading Hello.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Failed to install Hello.apk on device '192.168.56.101:5555': I/O error
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: I/O error
    [2014-12-22 21:00:17 - Hello] Launch canceled!
```

Sorry, but I am beginner do you can tell more info. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Do you have any device connected with ip 192.168.56.101??

Comment: I installed VirtualBox + Android and connect to Eclipse

Comment: Check the ip address of emulator you are trying to install your application on

Comment: You really don't need the whole `VM + Android` thing (first time I heard about in 5 years)... a simple AVD emulator is more than enough.

Comment: My AVD do very slow(

Comment: If your AVD is slow, you might wanna use Genymotion or install (if you're running an intel-powered CPU) Intel HAXM.
Read here concerning the second option : https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture
If you don't have an Intel-base computer, I'd suggest you check Genymotion.